# Postgres / Postgis query optimization

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, query-optimization, postgis

I have a query in Postgres / Postgis which is based around finding the nearest points of a given point filtered by some other columns in the table.

The table consists of a bit over 10 million rows and the query looks like this:

```
SELECT t.id FROM my_table t  
WHERE round(t.col1) IN (1,2,3) 
ORDER BY t.geom <-> st_transform(st_setsrid('POINT(lon lat)'::geometry, 4326), 3857)
LIMIT 1000;
```

The geom column is indexed using GIST and col1 is also indexed.
When the WHERE clause finds many rows that are also near the point this is blazing fast using the geom index:

```
Limit  (cost=0.42..10575.49 rows=1000 width=12) (actual time=0.150..6.742 rows=1000 loops=1)
->  Index Scan using my_table_geom_idx on my_table t  (cost=0.42..2148612.35 rows=203177 width=12) (actual time=0.149..6.663 rows=1000 loops=1)
     Order By: (geom <-> '.....'::geometry)
     Filter: (round(t.col1) = ANY ('{1,2,3}'::double precision[]))
     Rows Removed by Filter: 3348
Planning Time: 0.288 ms
Execution Time: 6.817 ms
```

The problem occurs when the WHERE clause does not find many rows that are close in distance to the given point. Example:

```
SELECT t.id FROM my_table t  
WHERE round(t.col1) IN (1) // 1 is very rare near the given point 
ORDER BY t.geom <-> st_transform(st_setsrid('POINT(lon lat)'::geometry, 4326), 3857)
LIMIT 1000;
```

This query runs much much slower:

```
Limit  (cost=0.42..14487.97 rows=1000 width=12) (actual time=8443.514..10629.745 rows=1000 loops=1)
->  Index Scan using my_table_geom_idx on my_table t  (cost=0.42..1962368.41 rows=135452 width=12) (actual time=8443.513..10629.553 rows=1000 loops=1)
     Order By: (t.geom <-> '.....'::geometry)
     Filter: (round(t.col1) = ANY ('{1}'::double precision[]))
     Rows Removed by Filter: 5866030
Planning Time: 0.292 ms
Execution Time: 10629.906 ms
```

I created an index on round(col1) trying to speed up searches on col1 but postgres uses the geom index only which works great when there are many rows nearby that fit the criteria but not so great if there are few rows that match.

If I remove the LIMIT clause Postgres uses the index on col1, which works great when there are few resulting rows but is very slow when the result contains many rows, so I would like to keep the LIMIT clause.

Any suggestions on how I could optimize this query or create an index that handles this?

EDIT:
Thank you for all the suggestions and feedback!

I tried the tip from @JGH and restricted my query using st_dwithin as to not order the entire table before limiting.

```
...where st_dwithin(geom, searchpoint, 10000)
```

This greatly reduced the time of the slow query, down to a few milliseconds. Restricting the search to a constant distance works well in my application, so I will use this as the solution.

Comment: Can you do `WHERE round(t.col1) <= 3`? Or `WHERE t.col1 < 3.5`?

Comment: No, I cannot change it because the query could be something like "IN (1, 5, 10)". The col1 column should be INT instead but due to some old migration it is double precision. The values are only integer and there is only 15 different possible values. Could changing it to INT increase the performance?

Comment: indexed columns used as arguments are harder to optimize. I'd still try `WHERE t.col1 < 3.5` and see what happens.

Comment: I tried `WHERE round(t.col1) <= 3` which is very fast since it matches on all 1,2 and 3 values where 1 is the only rare one. But this does not work work me since I need to filter by exact values. Using this approach I would have to do `WHERE round(col1) >= 1 AND round(col1) <= 1` which is as slow as the original query

Comment: the index on col1 should never be used... instead try to index `round(col1)`. It might be beneficial to restrict the spatial search too (`... where st_dwithin(geom, searchpoint, 10000)` instead of ordering the entire table before limiting the number of results.

Comment: rounding col1 dynamically in your query like that seems pretty weird.  Can you explain what the purpose of that is?  Why not round before storing?

Comment: @JGH Thanks I will try that! Also I was unclear in my explanation, the index for col1 is created with round(col1)

Comment: @jjanes It should be rounded before storing, the only reason to why we do it is because of some old values that were in this table which are not rounded, I will take the time to update them to their rounded values. However it is not the reason why it runs slowly.

Comment: Could you add a table with a list of the unique values in col1, have a boolean column called, say, "useThisValue", and set it to true for the values you want? Then, instead of the IN statement you use a join and WHERE useThisValue. Might be quicker...